# Language support problem

Tags: gnome, directory, language-support, input-language

I have a problem with the language support in Ubuntu 12.04LTS. I want to install Spanish in my computer and the system isn't able to find or create the directory that will allow the system to actually set Spanish as a language option inside Language support. So I am wondering how can I tell the system where are those files or how to fix this in any other way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following command on the terminal windows (CTRL+ALT+T)

```
export LANG=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LANGUAGE=es_ES:en
export LC_CTYPE=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_TIME=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_COLLATE=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_MONETARY=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_PAPER=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_NAME=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
export LC_ALL=

sudo update-locale LANG=es_ES.ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: it doesn't work: *** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8" LANGUAGE="en_GB:en_AU:en_CA:en" LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8" LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8" LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8" LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8" LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8" LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8" LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
 here what it says

Comment: still trying and it still says the same thing =(

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
locales is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.it is already installed, if I unistall it and reinstall it would it help?

Comment: Than you! I have solved my problem. I reinstalled the locales and then everything worked! thank for your help!